# Tricky washing machine waste problem

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine

first time on this forum but I could use some washing machine waste advice.

My brother and I are redecorating our entire house, including the rather small kitchen. We'd like to move the washing machine which is currently in the kitchen to make room for a dishwasher.

An ideal location for it would be at the top of the cellar stairs along with the tumble dryer. Running the hot and cold water lines shouldn't be a problem but the only waste drain location is outside the kitchen (the reason for the washing machine's current position) and the dining room is between the cellar stairs and the kitchen. The dining room has a concrete subfloor so running a pipe though this doesn't seem doable, especially with the right drop. The only option left that I can see is to run the waste pipe through the dining room ceiling but this presents the problem of gravity.

I've attached some pictures to help with understanding how things are laid out (excuse the mess but we're in the middle of redecorating). Open to any suggestions, however radical, although the cheaper the better.

[image: Top of cellar stairs]
[image: Dining room]
[image: Kitchen]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. How about an ejector pump to lift the wastewater to the level of a drainpipe? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Any chance of finding an alternate drainpipe to send the water to? Like a bath or toilet drain maybe?